# Java - get variable name from double array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Java array of type double with variable names used to store values as so:

```
double [] countArray = {teaCount, hotMealCount, drinkWaterCount, phoneCallCount};
```

I am looking to print the names of the variables out by it's index.

e.g. If I request `countArray[0]` it would return `teaCount` instead of the double that's stored.

Comment: I think a map<String, Double> is better for this issue.

Comment: Use a Map, Java doesn't work this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the names you need to store these

```
String[] countArray = {"teaCount", "hotMealCount", "drinkWaterCount", "phoneCallCount"};
```

Though most likely you wanted a `Map<String, Double>` such as

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("teaCount", teaCount);
map.put("hotMealCount", hotMealCount);
map.put("drinkWaterCount", drinkWaterCount);
map.put("phoneCallCount", phoneCallCount);
```

This stores both the name and the value it has.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it the way you want but the `Map` coould be your solution:

```
Map<String, Double> count = new HashMap<String, Double>();
count.put("teaCount", 1.5);
count.put("hotMealCount", 2.5);
// etc

count.get("teaCount"); // 1.5
```

Comment: just a note: you can't use double in containers, you have to use Double (with all the boxing/unboxing). Library that does it is http://trove.starlight-systems.com/

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible with this approach. A solution would be to have a `Map<String, Double>` where you store the name as key and the count as the value in the `Map`.

Actually the variable name is something temporarily and you cannot access the name later. And if you add something to an array you do not add the variable by name to the array but the value location.

Answer (score 0):

Yor are storing Strings, not double values in the array.

If you want to print the value of an index, just use:

System.out.println(countArray[0]);

And that will print teaCount.

Hope it works.

Comment: That's not what he is asking. Read the question again. He has an array storing double variables and he wants to get the name of the variable stored in a specific index of his array.